# ERROR xDB unavailable when submitting contact - certificates?

Tags: xdb

I have problem with my Sitecore 9.0.1 XP1 installation. The environment is Azure VMs with Azure SQL and is following:

- 2x CM VMs
- 2x CD VMs
- 1x xConnect + Sitecore Processing VM
- 1x Sitecore Reporting VM
- Azure SQL Premium Elastic Pool

I am using single public SSL certificate across all servers - it has Server and Client Authentication roles. I configured its thumbprint in all ConnectionStrings.config files

When launching CD/CM I am getting:

```
    69684 11:40:08 **ERROR xDB unavailable when submitting contact**.
Exception: Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.XdbUnavailableException
Message: xDB unavailable
Source: Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.ExecuteWithExceptionHandling[T](Func`2 func)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<LoadContact>b__0()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.OperationPerformanceMonitorExtensions.Monitor[T](OperationPerformanceMonitorBase monitor, Func`1 operation)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactRepository.LoadContact(ID contactId)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactRepository.MergeTemporaryContact(Contact contact)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.ContactRepository.SaveContact(Contact contact)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager.SubmitContact(Contact contact, Contact& realContact)

Nested Exception

Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
Message: An error occurred while sending the request.
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.Get[TEntity](IXdbContext context, IEntityReference`1 reference, ExpandOptions expandOptions, TimeSpan timeout)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.GetContactByIdentifier(IXdbContext xdbContext, String source, String identifier)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.ExecuteWithExceptionHandling[T](Func`2 func)

Nested Exception

Exception: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.ConnectionTimeoutException
Message: A task was canceled.
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.CollectionBatchWebApiClient.<ExecuteBatch>d__11.MoveNext()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException
Message: A task was canceled.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
```

Things tried/checked so far:

- Made sure no errors in certificate thumbprint in config files
- Added iis apppool identities to read certificate's private keys
- Checked and made sure that all 5x xConnect websites are available
  locally and from any other server (with no certificate errors)

**In Sitecore documentation they mention that xConnect server and client certificates are usually different - I have it configured on one SSL certificate - is that supported?**

Comment: Anything in the server’s log?

Comment: It turned out that I had incorrect 'collectionuser' SQL user's rights configured for xConnectCollection and this was preventing CDs and CMs from using xDB.
This link helped me:https://blog.baslijten.com/gotchas-while-installing-sitecore-9-using-the-sitecore-installation-framework/
Look under 'Note to self: do not forget to run the post-installation steps'