# Experience analytics throwing Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.ConnectionTimeoutException

Tags: xconnect, experience-analytics

We are getting below exceptions while trying to load graphs on the experience analytics dashboard. The dashboard timer keep on spinning and after few seconds we get the well known bunch of exceptions on the UI:

> The OnlineInteractions graph cannot be displayed due to a server
>   error. Contact you system administrator.

Whereas in CM logs we see `Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException` and `Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.ConnectionTimeoutException`, please see the stack trace below.

While debugging we already had a [look at this question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/13663/error-xdb-unavailable-when-submitting-contact-certificates) and make sure the `collectiouser` have a required rights on Shard databases. Though we don't see any post installation steps in 9.0.2 installation guide to execute such script, hence we assume on v9.0.2 it is being taken care while installation itself.

What could be other possible causes for this Timeout exception?

```
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
Message: An error occurred while sending the request.
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.Initialize(XmlNode configNode)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient(String clientConfigPath)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.Agents.TreeAggregatorAgent.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()

Exception: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.ConnectionTimeoutException
Message: A task was canceled.
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<ExecuteGetAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.ConfigurationWebApiClient.<Refresh>d__4.MoveNext()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException
Message: A task was canceled.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
```

**Logs in xDB Reference Data Service**

```
2019-03-12 13:27:52.417 -04:00 [Information] XConnect Test Host Application End, Machine: "VM-Name", Site: "stg9.xdb-reference-data.mydomain.com", AppId: "/LM/W3SVC/6/ROOT"
2019-03-12 13:28:31.531 -04:00 [Information] XConnect Test Host Application Start, Machine: "VM-Name", Site: "stg9.xdb-reference-data.mydomain.com", AppId: "/LM/W3SVC/6/ROOT"
2019-03-12 13:28:32.422 -04:00 [Information] Certificate Validation Filter Enabled, Thumbprint: mythumbprint
2019-03-12 13:28:32.422 -04:00 [Information] SSL Validation Filter Enabled
```

**Browser console logs on Experience Dashboard:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experience Analytics relies on both the Reporting Server of Sitecore and the Reference Data service of xConnect.

More often then not, this issue is because of an error occuring in the Reference Data service (which also relies on the Collection Search service)

To troubleshoot, I would examine the logs from the xConnect Reference Data service to see if there is a .NET error.

You may also have to look at the IIS access logs to see the request coming in from the Sitecore server and look at the result code.

Expect a 200 if everything is fine.

Expect a 403 if there are most likely certificate errors.

Expect a 500 if there are .NET errors.

Trying hard not to make this a link only answer as well as trying not to duplicate an answer already given, you may want to [Validate Your Install](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/17213/246) of Sitecore 9.0.2 using this helpful guidance.

Comment: Appreciate your inputs Pete. We verified the logs on xConnect Collection and xDB Reference Data instances. Looks like there are no transnational logs. All we see is the basis logging which I updated in my question above. Does that mean the CM is not even able to reach out the the xConnect instances (which is on a separate server on F5)? Though we see couple of 500 errors in the browser console.

Comment: Now you need to look at the IIS logs on xConnect.  Everytime you refresh the Analytics page, you'll see IIS requests going through the Reference Data Service.

Comment: What you are looking for is if the request is happening.

Comment: Pete, in xConnect collection as well there are just default logs. To me it looks like there are no activities at all on any of the IIS instance the xConnect VM. We developed a test application and thoroughly verified all the certs from CM. Not sure is it any database lock, excessive aggregation calls or incorrect configuration?

Comment: If you are taking about logs in the App_Data folder, you are looking st the wrong logs. I am taking about IIS logs.  These can be found typically in C:\inetlub\logs.  You're looking for logs that will show requests, IP's, useragents, and status codes.

Comment: Outside of that, its really hard to troubleshoot through this platform.