# Error when publishing language content

Tags: publishing, multilingual

I have just completed the whole `Sitecore XP` and `XC` installation, and I tried to remove the additional languages, and publish only the English language using the Smart Publish on the Content Editor. It's a completely new installation that runs without any issue. But, I'm having the following error:

```
job started: Publish to 'web'|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:deleted' event. ---> Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.ConnectionTimeoutException: A task was canceled. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<SendAsync>d__50.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.ReferenceData.ExperienceAnalyticsSegmentReader.GetDefinitionTypeKey()
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.ReferenceData.ExperienceAnalyticsSegmentReader.Get(Guid key, NameValueCollection readingPreferences)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.Events.SegmentDeployedEventHandler.DeleteSegment(Item deletedItem)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent[TArgs](EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator)
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.DeleteItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.PublishHelper.DeleteTargetItem(ID itemId)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.PerformAction.ExecuteAction(PublishItemContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.PerformAction.Process(PublishItemContext context)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.PublishItem.PublishItemPipeline.Run(PublishItemContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate entry, PublishContext context, List`1& referrers, List`1& children)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessPublishingCandidate(PublishingCandidate entry, PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.ProcessEntries(IEnumerable`1 entries, PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.ProcessQueue.Process(PublishContext context)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.PublishPipeline.Run(PublishContext context)
   at Sitecore.Publishing.Publisher.PublishWithResult()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.JobRunner.RunMethod(JobArgs args)
   at (Object , Object )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Jobs.DefaultJob.DoExecute()
   at Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseJob.ThreadEntry(Object state)
```

The error in the log file:

```
Exception Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.ConnectionTimeoutException: A task was canceled. ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<SendAsync>d__50.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.ReferenceData.ExperienceAnalyticsSegmentReader.GetDefinitionTypeKey()
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.ReferenceData.ExperienceAnalyticsSegmentReader.Get(Guid key, NameValueCollection readingPreferences)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.ReferenceData.ExperienceAnalyticsSegmentReader.Get(IEnumerable`1 keys, NameValueCollection readingPreferences)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.AggregatedSegmentReader.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Get>b__0(IReader`2 segmentReader)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<SelectManyIterator>d__17`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.AggregatedSegmentReader.Get(IEnumerable`1 keys, NameValueCollection readingPreferences)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Repositories.AggregationSegmentReader.Get(IEnumerable`1 keys, NameValueCollection readingPreferences)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.RequestTypeResolver.GetReportSegments()
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.RequestTypeResolver.GetRequestType()
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Http.ModelBinding.ReportQueryModelBinder.GetModelFromBindingContext(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Http.ModelBinding.ReportQueryModelBinder.BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinderParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.<ExecuteBindingAsyncCore>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
```

Current scenário:

- hyper-v VM with Windows 11
- Sitecore version 10.1.0
- Solr 8.4.0

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Is your xConnect domain accessible?

Comment: Yes, it is accessible.

Comment: Did you check [this](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17417/experience-analytics-throwing-sitecore-xdb-common-web-connectiontimeoutexception) similar question?

Comment: Yes, I did, not only the question as also every blog post related, I have tried almost everything related. :(